# How can I pass JSON data via HttpWebRequest - POST using VB.net?

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, httprequest

I've read a bunch of questions and tried a handful of different methods, so maybe my API service is just different. But this is my first time and I cant get it to work so I figured I'd post here and see if someone can educate me.

My code resulting in a response of error 400 - Bad request (API and other details changes for security)

```
Dim httpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://api.smtp2go.com/v3/users/smtp/add"), HttpWebRequest)
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"

        Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            Dim json As String = "{'api_key': ""api-123456123456123456123456"", 'username': ""user@domain.com"", 'description': ""Generated via API"" }"

            streamWriter.Write(json)
            streamWriter.Close()

        End Using

        Dim httpResponse = DirectCast(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Using streamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            Dim result = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
```

Their example in JavaScript

```
var url = "https://api.smtp2go.com/v3/users/smtp/add";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    'api_key': "api-123456123456123456123456",
    'username': "user@domain.com",
    'description': "Generated via API"
  }),
}).done(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}).fail(function(err) {
  throw err;
});
```

Their example in PHP

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json"
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,
  "https://api.smtp2go.com/v3/users/smtp/add"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array(
  "api_key" => "api-123456123456123456123456",
  "username" => "user@domain.com",
  "description" => "Generated via API"
)));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
```

Comment: have you tried using their JS and/or PHP examples, and do they actually work for you?

Comment: I have not, I suppose maybe I should to verify the system works at all.

Comment: have you ever found a solution? I am stuck with a returncode 400 in the same place...